# Give an example of a $G$ graph with a non-trivial group of automorphisms

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, finite-groups

> Give an example of a $G$ graph with a non-trivial group of automorphisms and such that after removing *any edge* from $G$ we get a graph with a trivial group of automorphisms.
> **Simplified variant:** Give an example of a G graph with a non-trivial group of automorphisms and such that after removing a *certain* edge from G we get a graph with a trivial group of automorphisms.

I tried to do simplified variant:

This one has identity and for example, symmetry about the dashed line:: 
[image: List item]

After removing a certain edge, we get a graph similar to this:
 [image: List item]

However I don't know whether this is correct and how to make the more difficult option.
Can you help me?

Comment: If you straighten out the bottom part to become a line pointing diagonally down, you still have mirror symmetry about an up-right, down-left diagonal line.

Comment: In fact, if a graph contains any triangle connected to the rest of the graph by only one vertex (there are two such in your second graph), then it has a non-trivial automorphism which simply swaps the two unconnected vertices of the triangle.

Comment: @Arthur I see now, so this is bad example. Sorry.

Comment: Trying out examples it turns out that most small graphs one would try ($K_n$ and $K_{n,m}$ for small $n,m$, cycles, paths, trees, and any graph that contains one of these as described by @TonyK) are 'highly symmetrical'. Apparently, graphs with no non-trivial automorphisms are called [asymmetric graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetric_graph) and one of the smallest examples known is the [Frucht graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frucht_graph) on six vertices. It may be that adding an edge to this graph will answer the simplified version.

Comment: **Hint for the simplified variant.** Can you find a nontrivial graph (more than one vertex) with a trivial automorphism group? Starting with that graph and adding one edge at a time, you will end up with a complete graph which has a nontrivial automorphism group. At some point in this process, adding an edge must turn a graph with trivial automorphism group into a graph with nontrivial automorphism group. Removing that last edge will turn a graph with nontrivial automorphism group into a graph with trivial automorphism group.

Answer (score 4):

**Lemma.** There is a connected graph $H$, with trivial automorphism group, in which each vertex has degree at least $3$.

**Proof.** Draw a graph of order $6$, with degree sequence $3,3,2,2,1,1$, which has a trivial automorphism group. Add an isolated vertex and you have a graph of order $7$, with degree sequence $3,3,2,2,1,1,0$, which has a trivial automorphism group. Its complement is a connected graph with trivial automorphism group and degree sequence $6,5,5,4,4,3,3$.

Trivially, an **empty graph** (no edges) will have the property that removing any edge leaves a graph with trivial automorphism group; presumably that's not what is wanted.

**Theorem.** There is a nonempty graph $G$ with nontrivial automorphism group such that, for each edge $e\in E(G)$, the graph $G-e$ has trivial automorphism group.

**Proof.** Let $H$ be a connected graph with trivial automorphism group in which each vertex has degree at least $3$. Let $H'$ be an isomorphic copy of $H$, disjoint from $H$. Let $V(H)=\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ and $V(H')=\{v_1',\dots,v_n'\}$, where the vertices are labeled so that the map $v_i\mapsto v_i'$ is the isomorphism from $H$ to $H'$. Let $G$ be the graph obtained from $H\cup H'$ by adding vertices $w_1,\dots,w_n'$ and edges $w_iv_i$ and $w_iv_i'$. The graph $G$ has a nontrivial automorphism which swaps $H$ with $H'$, but for any $e\in E(G)$, the graph $G-e$ has no nontrivial automorphism.

Note that, in the graph $G$, each vertex in the set $W=\{w_1,\dots,w_n\}$ has degree $2$, while all other vertices have degree at least $4$. Hence, in the graph $G-e$, each vertex in $W$ has degree at most $2$, while all other vertices have degree at least $3$. It follows that an automorphism of $G-e$ must fix the set $W$. This is the first step in showing that $G-e$ has no nontrivial automorphism. Assuming (without loss of generality) that the missing edge $e$ was incident to no vertex in $H$, the next step would be to show that the set $V(H)$ is fixed by any automorphism of $G-e$, then that $V(H)$ is pointwise fixed, then that $W$ is pointwise fixed, and finally that $V(H')$ is pointwise fixed.